# What is the technology most commonly used for iPhone - iPad communications?

Tags: iphone, ipad

What is the most commonly used technology for communicating between an application running on an iPad and one on an iPhone?  For example, the famous Scrabble application uses device-to-device communication to host the game board on the iPad and the letters on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth P2P connection.
Check [that](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html)